# Função para limpar html

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-5

Como fazer uma função que limpe o HTML? Tenho um campo que vem de um WS e preciso, antes de exibir na página, que limpe o HTML.

Me enviaram isso:

```
String result = Regex.Replace(htmlDocument, @"<[^>]*>", String.Empty);
```

Eu preciso colocar esse código numa função jquery, exatamente aqui e o `this.ShortDescription` é o cara que eu quero limpar. Como eu faço?

```
str += '<p>' + this.ShortDescription + '</p>';
```

O código acima é parte de uma função jQuery.

Comment: Como assim limpar o html?

Comment: @pnet, por exemplo sua entrada é `<p><strong>algum texto.....</strong></p>` e vc quer que alguma função retorne apenas `algum texto` é isso?

Answer (score 3):

Em javascript você pode usar:

```
document.body.innerHTML = '';
```

Comment: Eu tenho dificuldade com jquery e javascript. Eu tenho uma jquery que pega de um WS o texto, assim: str = str + this.Description; Depois descarrego a variável str na pagina e é montado tudo. Isso tá funcionando. Como eu agora removo as tags html do Description, conforme exemplo passado?

Comment: sim, mas como assim Description?

Comment: é o campo que eu pego na jquery do WS assim: this.Description; esse campo é que possui os textos que eu colocar na página. Como eu removo as tags dele?

Comment: @pnet tenta `this.Description.innerHTML = '';`

Comment: Não deu certo. Ficou undefined =

Comment: @pnet tenta postar mais partes do seu código para podermos entender melhor o seu problema...

Answer (score 0):

Eu uso o seguinte código vb.net:

```
Public Function limpaHTML_Recursiva(ByVal sTexto As String, ByVal j As Integer) As String
    If j = 0 Then
        Return sTexto
    End If
    Dim i As Integer = 0
    i = InStr(sTexto, "<")
    j = InStr(sTexto, ">")
    If i > 0 Then
        i -= 1
    End If
    sTexto = Left(sTexto, i) & Right(sTexto, sTexto.Length - j)
    Return (limpaHTML_Recursiva(sTexto, j))
End Function
```

Chama com :`sTexto = limpaHTML_Recursiva(sTexto, 1)`